# How to Pivot with Columns in SQL SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2005

Would you know if my script is missing anything additional, I am trying to pivot the Table "Pay_Details" and to have the month after month set on column rows with years on rows. I have tried the following and my script code has been posted.

I get the following error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

My output should look as follows:

```
Year     January     February    March
2019     150         120         230
2018     100         200         300
2017     90          110         120
```

[Script code]:

```
SELECT Server,
    DATEPART(year, date) [year], 
    DATEPART(quarter, date) [quarter], 
    DATEPART(month, date) [month], 
    DATEPART(day, date) [day],
    Payee,
    Amount

FROM   [dbo].[Pay_Details]

    (SELECT    DATEPART(year, date) [year], 
   DATEPART(quarter, date) [quarter], 
   DATEPART(month, date) [month], 
   DATEPART(day, date) [day],
   Payee,
   Amount

    ) p PIVOT ( MAX([Amount])
                FOR ColName IN ( DATEPART(year, date) [year], 
   DATEPART(quarter, date) [quarter], 
   DATEPART(month, date) [month], 
   DATEPART(day, date) [day],
   Payee,
   Amount

) ) AS pvt
ORDER BY [year] DESC, 
         [quarter], 
         [month], 
         [day]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pivot you are using aliases, you need to use literals. This means you either

a. Need to know the names of the columns you want before hand (unlikely as data will change)

b. build the pivot statement using dynamic sql. There are plenty of examples of how to do this on SO.

**However**, as you are trying to get a report in SSRS, there is no need to do any of this. If you use a Matrix control on your report, it will do the pivoting for you.

Here's a quick (from memory) guide on doing it.

Create a new report and add a new dataset. Set the query for this dataset to be something like

```
SELECT    DATEPART(year, date) [year], 
   DATEPART(quarter, date) [quarter], 
   DATEPART(month, date) [month], 
   DATENAME(month, date) [monthName], 
   DATEPART(day, date) [day],
   Payee,
   Amount
FROM Pay_Details
```

*notes: we don't actually need the payee, quarter and day columns in this example but you could extend it to include them you like.
I've also added a **monthName** column*

Now add a Matrix to the report design surface. You will a 2x2 table with placeholders for 'Columns', 'Rows' and 'Data'

Drag the `[year]` field from the dataset and drop it on 'Rows', drag `[month]` to 'Columns' and finally drag `[amount]` to 'Data'

That's it (almost)

Run the report and you'll see the data has been pivoted. The only problem is that your month columns show the month number, to fix this, click the cell containing the month number and select `[monthName]` from the list. The columns will still be sorted by number as the sorting is determined by the column group properties.